Postgres ssl connection certificate expiry
I am using connection via ssl in postgres. I passed below parameters to connect along with username and password.
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?" +
            "sslmode=verify-ca" +
            "&sslrootcert=root.crt"+
         

I am able to connect via ssl with expired certificates as well. Ideally it should not connect.
Is there any mechanism which is checking the certificate expiry for root.crt file from postgres code ?

Do you mean the root certificate expired but the certificate issued by the root certificate is not expired? Sounds like a broken setup.

both the certificates are expired. @steffen Ullrich

I can't reproduce.  An expired server cert causes an error for me.  Can you show a simple, complete, self contained java file which reproduces the issue?  What if you use psql rather than java?

psql is giving the error check via java code
